# d3.js Prevent `rotate` property from parent group

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to prevent the `text` from accessing the `rotate` property from parent node, how can I do that?

here is the demo:

```js
// largely based on http://bl.ocks.org/4063550

// some made-up data
var data = [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3];

// tree-ify our fake data
var dataTree = {
    children: data.map(function(d) { return { size: d }; })
};

// basic settings
var w = 400,
    m = 20,
    maxRadius = 40,
    padding = 10;


// size scale for data
var radiusScale = d3.scale.sqrt()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
    .range([0, maxRadius]);

// determine the appropriate radius for the circle
var roughCircumference = d3.sum(data.map(radiusScale)) * 2 +
        padding * (data.length - 1),
    radius = roughCircumference / (Math.PI * 2);

// make a radial tree layout
var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([360, radius])
    .separation(function(a, b) {
        return radiusScale(a.size) + radiusScale(b.size);
    });

// make the svg
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w + m * 2)
    .attr("height", w + m * 2)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w / 2 + m) + "," + (w / 2 + m) + ")");

// apply the layout to the data
var nodes = tree.nodes(dataTree);

// create dom elements for the node
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(nodes.slice(1)) // cut out the root node, we don't need it
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ") translate(" + d.y + ")";
      })

node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return radiusScale(d.size); });
node.append("text")
.attr("transform", function(d) {
         return "rotate(" + (2 * d.x) + ")";
      })
.text("testing a word");
```

```css
circle {
   fill: steelblue;
   stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to go about it would be to simply offset the initial `rotate` value of the parent node in the child node. Hence, the code for adding text will look something like:

```
node.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
         return "rotate(" + -(d.x - 90) + ")";
      })
    .text("testing a word");
```

Here's a link to a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/51y0cjek/).